# How to display custom error message on EditForm Template of AspXGrid?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, edititemtemplate

DevExpress AspXGrid has a cool editform template that you can use it several ui style as popup form or inline form betwwen grid rows etc..

When you unimplement Update Event of grid and if you allow grid to editing from settings, it shows the EditForm, but when you fire update button at this state, it shows a cool Error Message like "Specified method is not supported"..

I want to write some custom message in the same place of that message.

Anyone knows how can i do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ASPxDataValidationEventArgs.RowError](http://help.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebDataASPxDataValidationEventArgs_RowErrortopic.aspx) property to specify the error text displayed within the [Error Row](http://help.devexpress.com/AspNet/CustomDocument3775.aspx). This row is automatically displayed below the [Edit Form](http://help.devexpress.com/AspNet/CustomDocument3710.aspx) if the **RowError** property is set to a not empty string.

Please, also take a look at the [GridEditing/Validation](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/Validation.aspx) demo module and ASPxGridView [documentation](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowValidatingtopic).

Comment: Thank you MrDmitry, the information that you gave is very usefull.